# How to use Increment Operator inside Ngoninit()?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, local-storage, command-line-interface

I am using increment operator to change a value of a variable inside ngoninit() but the compiler is giving me this error:

```
error TS2356: An arithmetic operand must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint' or an enum type.
```

My code inside ngoninit() :

```
  ngOnInit() {
      if(!localStorage.getItem("tempuid")) {
        localStorage.setItem("tempuid","0");
      }
      let uid = localStorage.getItem("tempuid");
      uid++;
      localStorage.setItem("tempuid",uid);
  }
```

I want to increment the value of "uid" or is there some other way to do this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: `localStorage.setItem("tempuid","0");` the uid is stored as a string. Have you tried to convert it to a number like: `let uid = +localStorage.getItem("tempuid");`

Comment: komal's answer did it. Thanks all of you for your time

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can Try this code. I hope it will helps you.

```
  ngOnInit() {
          if(!localStorage.getItem("tempuid")) {
            localStorage.setItem("tempuid","0");
          }
          let uid:any = localStorage.getItem("tempuid");
          uid++;
          localStorage.setItem("tempuid",uid);
      }
```

Comment: This answer is different, but worse, because it throws away type information entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Your `uid` is of type `string` try casting it to number or any

**right way** will be cast it to number

```
let uid = parseInt(localStorage.getItem("tempuid"));
          uid++;
```

Or you can rid of this error Using any

```
let uid:any = localStorage.getItem("tempuid");
      uid++;
```

Comment: @Bravo yes it will work with any but better way would be to cast it as number

Comment: yes, it even works in javascript (not sure why I though it didn't)

Comment: @Bravo you can get an idea even from error `An arithmetic operand must be of type 'any', 'number', 'bigint'`

Comment: @IngoBürk sry it was a typo just updated the ans thanks for pointing it out

Answer (score 1):

Just parse the storage data into `Number`:

```
let uid = Number(localStorage.getItem("tempuid"));
uid++;
```